# Cycle Pager auto advance with Pause/Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

I've managed to work out who to make a pager gallery using the cycle plugin WITH auto advance

```
$(function () {
    $('#s4').before('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 6000,
        pager: '#nav',
        before: function () {
            if (window.console)
                console.log(this.src);
        }
    });
});
```

However as this takes away some control from the user so it's be great to add a play/pause button like this (preferably one button)
[play pause buttons here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pause.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var slides = $('#s4').before('<div id="nav" class="nav"><button id="play_pause" class="pause">Pause</button></nav>')
.cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  'slow',
    timeout: 6000,
    pager:  '#nav',
    before: function() { if (window.console) console.log(this.src); }
});    

$('#pauseButton').click(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.hasClass('pause')) {
        obj.removeClass('pause').addClass('play').text('Play');
        slides.cycle('pause'); 
    } else if (obj.hasClass('play')) {
        obj.removeClass('play').addClass('pause').text('Pause');
        slides.cycle('resume');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but couldn't get that working - should i be putting

$(function() {

before your code?

Comment: Yes you will need to wrap it in one of the versions of the jquery document ready code.